# Connecting to Gest ip address usign host alias

Tags: networking, redhat, virtual-machines, hostname, hosts

I have RedHat OS running on VMWare Player. My host operating system is windows7. Network configuration i am using on my virtual machine is NAT.

I have configured my Guest operating systems /etc/hosts to have following configuration.

```
[ora112@jipsl01t ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1               localhost
192.168.179.129         jipsl01t jipsl01t.com
```

when i ping from my host operating system, i can ping to 192.168.179.129, but i can not ping to hostname (`jipsl01t` ) or hostname alias (`jipsl01t.com`).

could anybody help me to understand why this is not working.

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the HOST is Windows 7 and GUEST is redhat.

So, if you want to resolve the names `jipsl01t` and  `jipsl01t.com` from you HOST machine, you need to include hostname to IP address mapping details in the `hosts` file of your HOST machine, NOT on GUEST machine.

In windows the path for hosts file is :

`C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`